# Guile build error on linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, build, guile

I get the following error(s), when building [guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/). The error is with both the versions, [version 2.2.2](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/guile/guile-2.2.2.tar.gz), version 2.2.0 and [version 2.0.14](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/guile/guile-2.0.14.tar.gz)

```
fports.c: In function 'fport_input_waiting':
fports.c:626:10: error: variable 'pollfd' has initializer but incomplete type
   struct pollfd pollfd = { fdes, POLLIN, 0 };
fports.c:626:34: error: 'POLLIN' undeclared (first use in this function)
   struct pollfd pollfd = { fdes, POLLIN, 0 };
fports.c:626:17: error: storage size of 'pollfd' isn't known
   struct pollfd pollfd = { fdes, POLLIN, 0 };
```

I build the package with the following steps:

```
$ wget "$DOWNLOAD_URL"
$ tar xzf guile-{$VERSION}.tar.gz
$ cd guile-${VERSION}
$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/.local --disable-static --disable-networking
$ make -j 12
```

**[UPDATE>** I had installed `libunistring-0.9.7` and `gc-7.6.0` to `$HOME/.local`, so I used the following `./configure` command, but to no better result.

```
$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/.local \
              --with-libunistring-prefix=$HOME/.local \
              --with-sysroot=$HOME/.local \
              --with-libgmp-prefix=$HOME/.local \
              --with-threads                              ## updated configure command
```

`config.log` says

```
451 configure:8023: checking for poll.h
452 configure:8023: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
453 configure:8023: $? = 0
454 configure:8023: result: yes
```

Looking a little deeper, I see that the required file `poll.h` seems to
be defined in `lib/poll.h`

But I also have a `poll.h` in the `/usr/include/poll.h` which
redirects to `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/poll.h`

There is also `libguile/poll.h` which redirects to `libguile/__scm.h`
And here is `__scm.h` there is no definition of `struct pollfd`

There seems to be something wrong while configuring the package.

I am using an Ubuntu server. And the sysadmin route may take a
little more than usual. So I prefer building and installing a local
package.

I am trying to compile with `gcc-4.8`

Does anyone know how to get it to compile?

Comment: Why not contact guile maintainers on the mailing list or IRC? `2.2.2` is an 1 day old release when you asked the question. And you should provide the Ubuntu version that you are using. A week ago I've managed to compile the 2.2.0 on Ubuntu 14.04. Are you able to compile 2.2.0 version?

Comment: I had mailed to the maintainers, and awaiting a reply. Tried with v2.2.0 but the same result.

Comment: I downloaded the zip file for Guile2.2.2, unzipped into a new directory `~/Guile` (on ubuntu 16.04) then ran `./configure`   The resulting script did not post any errors, but  `Makefile` was not produced.  Now, what do I do?

Comment: @hell_ical_vortex Here is my snippet with the compile notes: https://gitlab.com/snippets/1657244 You also could check this "Linux from scratch" [guide](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/guile.html). IMO the `poll.h` problems suggest something is not right with the installed kernel headers on your computer: packages `linux-headers-generic`, `linux-headers-X.XX.XXX` and `linux-headers-X.XX.XXX-generic` where X.X.XXX is the version of the `Ubuntu` kernel package you are using.

Comment: @user3629249 Here is my configure output: https://gitlab.com/snippets/1657244#configure-output Note that you need 3 libraries to be installed before this: `sudo apt-get install libunistring-dev libgc-dev libffi-dev` - these libraries are required.

Comment: @hell_ical_vortex I've tried to compile `2.2.2` and I'm able to do it using my notes in the snippet above.

Comment: @zloster,  I installed the three libraries you mentioned.  then entered: `./configure && make -f Makefile`   it all ran to completion, with on a couple of minor warnings, like a returned value being ignored .  So the `guile 2.2.2` works.  Suggest you ignore the earlier versions of `guile`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on centos 7.
I added `#include <sys/poll.h>` to the source file, `fports.c`, which had the problem.

Then, `./configure CFLAGS="-std=gnu11"`